# Pure javascript horizontal marquee of inline-block elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a marquee using inline block elements. 
My problem, currently, is achieving infinite scrolling in an efficient way. 
The end of the scroll looks like this:

[image: end]

And the start position is:

[image: start]

But I need to achieve an infinite effect. I'm not sure how to go about this, either by swapping the elements inside or something else.

Can you please help me with what's left of this little project?

For reference, this is how the end position shoud look like:

[image: end-desired]

The code is simple ([See CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/whgne)):

HTML

```
<div class="viewport" id="viewport">
  <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div><div 
    class="item">2</div><div 
    class="item">3</div><div 
    class="item">4</div><div 
    class="item">5</div><div 
    class="item">6</div><div 
    class="item">7</div><div 
    class="item">8</div><div 
    class="item">9</div><div 
    class="item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.viewport {
  position:      relative;
  margin:        0 auto;
  padding:       20px 0;
  width:         200px
}
.wrapper {
  position:      relative;
  display:       inline-block;
  white-space:   nowrap;
  transition:    0.8s ease-in-out all;
}
.item {
  display:       inline-block;
  width:         25px;
  height:        25px;
}
```

JS

```
var scroller = document.getElementById('wrapper');

function start() {
  for ( var i = 0; 
       i < scroller.children.length; 
       i++ ) { 

    (function(j) { 
      var timeout = 1000*j;
      setTimeout(function() { 

        var left = -scroller.children[j].offsetWidth * j,
            leftPx = left + 'px';

        scroller.style.left = leftPx;

      }, timeout)
    })(i); 
  }
}
start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you want to know how to keep the function going and not how to animate it back. Call a function `MyFunction();` at the end of the start, and at the end of that call `start`. For example:

```
    var scroller = document.getElementById('wrapper');

function start() {
  for ( var i = 0; 
       i < scroller.children.length; 
       i++ ) { 

    (function(j) { 
      var timeout = 1000*j;
      setTimeout(function() { 

        var left = -scroller.children[j].offsetWidth * j,
            leftPx = left + 'px';

        scroller.style.left = leftPx;

      }, timeout)
    })(i); 
  }
  MyFunction();
}

// Reverse function here
start();
```

Alternatively, you can use the `<marquee>` tag instead of all this script.

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking for. See http://als.musings.it/ for an example with jQuery

Comment: Right, that's the idea. I'm looking for a good and efficient way to do it. I'm also fiddling with a way that I'll post as an answer, but I'd like to see other people's views into how to solve this